# Update a particular field in django forms and not be able to edit the others

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to create a expense claim app, i have created a form where a user can claim a expense ,when the admin Logs in the following webpage in the picture appears and the webpages iterates all the claims that have claim_status == Null, i want the admin to be able to accept or reject the claim from the dropdown and it to update the value for that object in the database and webpage to refresh and that claim showing no more

[image: This is the admin page where i am displaying the data regarding the claim i just want admin to accept or reject the claim using the dropdown and that field to update for that particular claim]

I have given a initial value of Null for the ExpenseClaim model and when user fills the expense claim form he cannot see the claim_status field

please see my models

```
class ExpenseClaim(models.Model):
    reference_number        = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    employee_name           = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    employee_ID             = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    claim_initiating_date   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    invoice_date            = models.DateField()
    invoice_location        = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    biller_name             = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    invoice_category        = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price                   = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=False , default=0.00) 
    GST                     = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2 ,max_digits=10, null=False , default=0.00) 
    CGST                    = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2 ,max_digits=10, null=False , default=0.00)
    IGST                    = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=False , default=0.00)
    Total_amount            = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2 ,max_digits=10, null=False , default=0.00)
    mode_of_payement        = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Payment_reference       = models.BooleanField()
    invoice                 = models.FileField()
    claim_status            = models.CharField(default=None , max_length=10)
    payment_status          = models.CharField(default= None , max_length=10)
```

Following is my models field i tried to create a new form but that just creates a new object in the database i want to update the existing one

```
invoice_category_choices =[
    ('food',"food"),
    ('travel',"travel"),
    ('accodmodation',"accomodation"),
    ('fuel',"fuel"),
    # ('others',"others"),

]

claim_status_choices = [
    ('accepted' , 'accepted'),
    ('rejected' , 'rejected')
]

payment_status_choices =[
    ('paid' , 'paid'),
    ('notpaid' , 'notpaid') 
]

class ExpenseClaimForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExpenseClaim
        exclude = [
            "employee_name",
            "employee_ID",
            "claim_status",
            "payment_status"
        ]  
        widgets = {
        'invoice_date': forms.DateInput(format=('%m/%d/%Y'), attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Select a date', 'type':'date'}),
        'invoice_category':forms.Select(choices= invoice_category_choices),
        'claim_status':forms.Select(choices= claim_status_choices)
        
    }
            
class ClaimStatusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExpenseClaim
        fields = [
            "claim_status",
            
        ]
        widgets = {
        'claim_status':forms.Select(choices= claim_status_choices)
        
    }
```

Comment: Are you want update only `claim status` ?? or update all ??

Comment: @RiyasAc  only claim_status rest fields display only

Comment: please add view and html

Answer (score 0):

**forms.py**

```
class ClaimStatusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExpenseClaim
        fields = [
            "claim_status",
            
        ]
        widgets = {
        'claim_status':forms.Select(choices= claim_status_choices)
        
    }
```

**views .py**

```
def admin_update_view(request , reference_number):  
  post = get_object_or_404(ExpenseClaim , reference_number=reference_number)
  form = ClaimStatusForm(instance=post)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    post = get_object_or_404(ExpenseClaim , reference_number=reference_number)
    form = ClaimStatusForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      claim_status = form.cleaned_data.get('claim_status')

      post.claim_status = claim_status
      post.save()
      return redirect('/admin/')

  context  = { "form":form , "initialize_context" : initialize_context(request)}
  return render(request , 'graphauth/adminupdate.html' , context)
```

**urls.py**

```
 path('adminupdate/<int:reference_number>', views.admin_update_view , name='adminupdate'),
```

**admin.html**

```
<a href="/adminupdate/{{items.reference_number}}" class=""btn btn-secondary">update</a>
```